# ROS Answers SE migration: ant & gradle

Tags: ros, gradle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

thanking you in advance..
I have to run and test any project of RosJava. i followed rosjava wiki but couldnot get any clear understanding of building rosjab

After following some sample programs from following link i get this error after typing "ant"
[link text](http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_ROSJava_to_Program_the_iRobot_Create_to_Move)

**Error Found**
/home/ahmedshah/ros_workspace/robot_mover_java/build.xml:19: ros.properties is missing.  Please type 'rosmake' first

after searching ROS questions and answers i found to use GRADLE, i really want to know what basically the gradle is?? does it replace "ant" ?? and How ?? and how it can be used to build rosjava program?? any useful link (in which there is a program too) will be helpful me too ..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44124/ant-&-gradle/) by [AhmedShah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3229/ahmedshah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to use google to find out about gradle.

[Gradle homepage](http://www.gradle.org/)

Gradle replaces ant, it is based on Maven and Groovy.

The rosjava documentation and tutorials explain how to use gradle:
[rosjava wiki](http://ros.org/wiki/rosjava_core/Tutorials)

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0